# How can I show that an odd degreed polynomial with coefficients in the real space always has a root in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

How can I show that every odd degreed polynomial with coefficients in the real space will have a real root?

Comment: Draw graphs of $x$, $x^3$, $x^5$, and so on. This should suggest how to use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $f$ be an odd degree polynomial. What is $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)?$
What is $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x)?$

Can you now use Intermediate value theorem to conclude your result?

Comment: you men $x\to \infty$ and $x\to -\infty$

Comment: @user44197: sorry- that's what I meant. Let me edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Show that the limits of the polynomial $f(x)$ as $x \to \pm \infty$  have opposite signs. So when $x$ goes from some large negative value to some large positive value, the polynomial changes sign. So somewhere in between there must  be a root.

Answer (score 1):

[IVT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) and the continuity of the polynomial function gives the obvious answer. You can also notice that complex roots of a polynomial with real coefficients occur in conjugate pairs so there's an even number of them. Since the total number of roots is odd, there's at least one real root. A third way could be an application of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) rule.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Intermediate Value Theorem and continuity of polynomials, which is sufficient (but not necessary) for having the Intermediate Value Property. W.l.o.g.,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} p(x)/x^n = -\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} p(x)/x^n=1 $$
but odd polynomials switch signs between $-x$ and $x$. Apply the IVT.